# Rails devise unique email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

Is there a built-in method in devise that i can check whether or not a given username or email is unique against all existing usernames and emails. (Say if i don't want to validate when making the model)
i can just say

```
if user.is_unique?
     execute some code here
end
```

Im using rails 3, and my gemfile just says gem 'devise' (so it gets most recent), if that info is important

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such a method but you can add it by yourself to `User` model. Try this:

```
def is_email_unique?
  !(User.all - [self]).map(&:email).include?(self.email)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your User model:

```
def is_unique?
  !User.exists?(:email => email) && !User.exists?(:username => username)
end
```